# Where and how does ethernet header get added/deleted in Linux stack?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ethernet

I had two question relating to code implementation in the Linux networking stack:

1. I see that "struct eth_header_ops" is used to add ethernet header to a IP packet. But I am unable to find how the functions inside it are invoked, and which function is supposed to do what. What is the code flow for this?
2. Similarly, when does the ethernet header get removed on an incoming frame? Could you show the path from the NIC driver to the place where the header is actually removed?

thank you.

Comment: `eth_header_ops` is ancient; what Linux kernel version are you looking at?

Comment: 4.18, in ether_setup. How else does ethernet header get added?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is done as part of ip_finish_output2(). But I would really like some experts to throw more light into the flow for TX and RX wrt ethernet header manipulation.